# Armadillo's print() method and cout are inconsistent in order when called from Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

Lately, I've been using `RcppArmadillo`, but I've noticed some inconsistencies in the print order of certain objects. Particularly, when using `cout` and `print()`. Sometimes, `print()` will be printed first, then `cout`; and other times it's the other way around.

I do not understand exactly why this is happening. I suppose `cout` and `print()` are called asynchronously and hence the difference in order, but why is this happening? And how can it be prevented?

#### Example

If I have the following `test_order.cpp` file

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test(int n){

  cout << "Print 1\n";
  arma::mat X(n, n);
  cout << "Print 2\n";
  X.print();
  cout << "Print 3\n";

  return 1;

}
```

And call it from R like this

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp("test_order.cpp")

test(3)
```

I get different results when printing. Three different results are the following:

```
> test(3)
  2.1220e-314            0  6.9531e-310Print 1
Print 2

  2.3044e-314  6.9275e-310  6.9532e-310
  2.1916e-314  2.1916e-314  2.2718e-314
Print 3
[1] 1
```

```
> test(3)
  Print 1
Print 2
6.9531e-310  2.3044e-314  4.9407e-324
  6.9532e-310  2.1916e-314  4.9407e-324
            0  6.9275e-310  4.9407e-324
Print 3
[1] 1
```

```
> test(3)
  6.9531e-310  2.3044e-314  4.9407e-324
  6.9532e-310  2.1916e-314  4.9407e-324
            0  6.9275e-310  4.9407e-324Print 1
Print 2

[1]Print 3
 1
```

Comment: Use `Rcout` as recommended. Doing that, I don't see the problem in RStudio whereas the issue is even worse than what you show with `cout`.

Comment: Roland is 100% correct. The issue is discussed in _Writing R Extensions_ and is an _R issue_ orthogonal to Rcpp:  you are supposed to use _only R's output facilities_ for the very reason you observe here.

Comment: Related, of course, is the fact we do in fact redirect Armadillo's output to R's so the two are in sync.  It is really only the manual `std::cout` (or `printf()`) that is bad, and for that use `Rcpp::Rcout` and `Rprintf()`, respectively.  We can't automate that further, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland)'s and [Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel)'s comments, as well as [Dirk's book](http://www.rcpp.org/book/) and [this Rcpp article](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-rcout/), the solution is to use `Rcout` instead of `cout` and `print()`.

According to [Dirk's book](http://www.rcpp.org/book/):

> Because R provides the “shell” around our statistical computing,
>   programs need to synchronize their (printed) output with R which uses
>   its own buffering.

In addition that CRAN maintainers flag code that includes `std::cout`.

So the `test_order.cpp` file should be like this:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test(int n){
    Rcout << "Print 1\n";
    arma::mat X(n, n);
    Rcout << "Print 2\n";
    Rcout << X << "\n";
    Rcout << "Print 3\n";

    return 1;
}
```